# HTML Input only works at front of input field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dojo

I have a web page with an odd behavior on part of it.

On most of the page, the input tags work just the way one would expect.

Here's an input tag I put in to test:

```
<input name="vanilla1" value="vanilla" />
```

In one part of the page, I can click on the field to edit it, but only at the front of the field.  So, if the input tag had a value of "vanilla", I could click in front of the "v" and start typing or deleting.  But it won't let me click between the two "l" characters and start typing.

It's not easy to just post a full working sample, I would have to retype by hand a lot of code.

If I **wanted** to get that behavior I don't have a clue of how to do it.

Any ideas of what to look for that might cause this?

It's obviously not disabled or readonly because I can edit it.
When I inspect the problem input tags in the IE DOM explorer, they don't look any different from the input tags that work as expected.

There's javascript, html, angularJS and dojo, plus the esri gis api css libraries in the technical mix.

A few more observations:

In IE, when I click on a working input tag that already has a value in it, I get a little X show up on the far right of the input box.  If I click on the X the field is blanked out.  On my problem input tags, when I click on them, I get the X but clicking the X does not work.  So I appear to be accessing the right object.

When I inspect the object, everything looks normal.  No javascript events attached, it's not read only or disabled.

Comment: Without any code/external context, it's hard to understand what you mean? Could you maybe just post the snippet of code you're referring to? If not, maybe a screenshot?

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, but at least I'm moving in the right direction.

The input tag is inside a tag that has the draggable="true" attribute turned on.  If I change draggable to false, the input works as it should.

Don't know why yet, but at least I have something to work with.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it like covered by another node or something like that?
Did you check it in all browsers or only in IE?

Try to open Chrome DevTools and click the "Select an element in the page to inspect it" (top left corner of the DevTools window, `CTRL + Shift + C` shortcut on Windows) and hover over that input. See if there's possibly any element that may cover it. If there's - voila! Remove that overlay and you're good to go. If not - I don't have any ideas for now.

Comment: Michal, Can't put chrome on the box.   There don't seem to be any objects overlaid over it.  I can inspect the item using IE or Firefox and I get the right input tag, not something else.